# Не запускается виртуальная машина

Tags: virtualbox

помогите пожалуйста запустить виртуальную машину через vagrant

vagrant1.6.3windows7(64)virtualBox 4.1

сделал всё по инструкции, в результате машина запустилась. [скриншот](http://prozaik.16mb.com/misc/vd.png). но не понятно как с ней работать. в статусе virtualBox написано, что она работает, а где она сама не найду...

Comment: На правах слоупока: vagrant по умолчанию запускает виртуалки в headless-режиме, т.е. без gui. В этом случае предполагается взаимодействие с машиной через консольное подключение, с linux-коробками это подключение включается через vagrant ssh, с windows, скорее всего, тоже.

Comment: Памяти и видеопамяти что-то очень мало.

Comment: @Etki, тут не только gui, но и консоли нету... Или это нормально?

Comment: @Qwertiy потому что подключение ведется по ssh

Answer (score 2):

vagrant по умолчанию запускает виртуалки в headless-режиме, т.е. без gui. В этом случае предполагается взаимодействие с машиной через консольное подключение, с linux-коробками это подключение включается через vagrant ssh, с windows, скорее всего, тоже.

<sub>вынесено из коммента Etki</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите на сайт http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html скачайте от туда extpack и установите его в виртуалбокс.Должно помощь в данной проблеме, у многих помогало.

Answer (score 0):

тоже были такие проблемы, пока не скачала VirtualBox с этого сайта https://virtualbox-download.ru/ . Все работает отлично, без глюков, никаких нареканий.